# jOOQ 3.15 postgres complaining about jsonb types in generated sql

Tags: jooq

The following runtime error popped up after upgrading my jOOQ version from 3.14 -> 3.15.3:

`ERROR: column "old_values" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying`

The code looks like:

```
final String jsonChanges = gson.toJson(map);
final InsertOnDuplicateStep<TicketLogRecord> insertLogs =
                insertInto(LOG,
                           LOG.ID,
                           LOG.OLD_VERSION,
                           LOG.OLD_VALUES,
                           LOG.NEW_VALUES)
                .select(
                        select(field("to_update.id", UUID.class),
                                field("to_update.version", Integer.class),
                                val("{}", JsonElement.class),
                                val(jsonChanges, JsonElement.class),
)
final var countUpdated =
                with("to_update", "id", "version", "state_id").as(ids)
                                                                      .with("update_states").as(updateWhere.returning())
                                                                      .with("insert_logs").as(insertLogs.returning())
                                                                      .select(count().as("updated_count"))
                                                                      .from("to_update");
            return using(configuration)
                .fetchOne(countUpdated)
                .getValue("updated_count", Integer.class);
```

It was resolved by casting `cast(val("{}", JsonElement.class), LOG.OLD_VALUES)` and likewise with NEW_VALUES on the line below it. But I'm interested in why this issue with SQL generation arose between these two minor versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why is this happening / "regressing"?

This usage here:

```java
val(jsonChanges, JsonElement.class)
```

Is making use of an undocumented "feature", that happened to work by accident in *some cases* (not always). It seems to have worked for you in your case. However, only class literals supported by [`SQLDataType`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/SQLDataType.html) can be passed to methods like [`DSL.val(Object, Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Class)), so this is valid:

```java
field("to_update.version", Integer.class)
```

But passing `JsonElement` isn't. jOOQ can't possibly know how you intend to bind a `JsonElement` value to the JDBC driver. It might have worked because somewhere, you've registered a `Binding<Object, JsonElement>`, and because that binding is (historically) added to an internal static `DataType` registry, looking up a binding for `JsonElement.class` happened to work sometimes. Reasons why it might not work:

- The class registering the `Binding<Object, JsonElement>` has not been loaded yet
- An internal refactoring in jOOQ changes some of these undocumented lookup behaviours

This definitely deserves some attention in jOOQ:

- [#12470](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12470) Better Javadoc
- [#12471](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12471) Logging a warning when users try to lookup unsupported class literals

#### How to fix it?

In your particular case, you already have a reference to a `DataType<JsonElement>` in `LOG.OLD_VALUES`. Your cast can work, but even better, just remove the `JsonElement.class` literal entirely and write this instead:

```java
// Assuming your JSON library is Gson
val(new JsonObject(), LOG.OLD_VALUES)
```

This will take the `DataType` from the `OLD_VALUES` column (including its binding), and use that to bind the `JsonObject` value.